# Remove the rows that have the same column A value but different column B value from df (but not vice-versa) in R

Tags: r

I’m trying to remove all the rows that have the same value in the "lan" column of my dataframe but different value for my "id" column (but not vice-versa).

Using an example dataset:

```
require(dplyr)
t <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                           4L), lan = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
                                                  7L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), class = "factor"), 
                    value = c(0.22988498, 0.848989831, 0.538065821, 0.916571913, 
                              0.304183372, 0.983348167, 0.356128559, 0.054102854, 0.400934593, 
                              0.001026817, 0.488452667)), .Names = c("id", "lan", "value"
                              ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
t
```

I need to get rid of rows 1 and 10 because they have the same lan (a) but different id.

I've tried the following, without success:

```
a<-t[(!duplicated(t$id)),]
c<-a[duplicated(a$lan)|duplicated(a$lan, fromLast=TRUE),]
d<-t[!(t$lan %in% c$lan),]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And an alternative using `dplyr`:

```
t2 <- t %>% 
  group_by(lan,id) %>%
  summarise(value=sum(value)) %>%
  group_by(lan) %>%
  summarise(number=n()) %>%
  filter(number>1) %>%
  select(lan)

> t[!t$lan %in% t2$lan ,]
   id lan      value
2   2   b 0.84898983
3   2   c 0.53806582
4   3   d 0.91657191
5   3   d 0.30418337
6   4   e 0.98334817
7   4   e 0.35612856
8   4   e 0.05410285
9   4   f 0.40093459
11  4   g 0.48845267
```

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot Akrun. You cannot imagine how many times I have said the same thing for your solutions :). I would still be typing thank you comments I think!  Your solution was excellent and fast!!

Comment: Happy to have helped Alicia! :)

Comment: Using @akrun code:                                 
>indx1 <-  with(data, duplicated(LAN)|duplicated(LAN,fromLast=TRUE))
>indx2 <- !(duplicated(data[,c("Patient.ID","LAN")])|duplicated(data[,c("Patient.ID","LAN")],fromLast=TRUE))
>d<-data[!(indx1 & indx2),]
>dim(d)
[1] 3936971      28

Comment: Using @LyzanderR code:
>data$value <- 0
>t2 <- data %>% 
  group_by(LAN,Patient.ID) %>%
  summarise(value=sum(value)) %>%
  group_by(LAN) %>%
  summarise(number=n()) %>%
  filter(number>1) %>%
  select(LAN)
>d2<-data[!data$LAN %in% t2$LAN ,]
>dim(d2)
[1] 3912020      29

Comment: For some reason the solutions you propose don't yield the same results for me. My dataset: `dim(data)` [1] 3936979 28

Comment: Hi Alicia. I double checked by code and it seems to be able to catch and remove the rows you want. I also know that Akrun's code is usually optimal. So, according to the dataset you gave us both codes seem to work fine. In your bigger dataset there might be cases not captured in one of the codes because of some condition not being present in the small dataset (this happens a lot unfortunately, it is not your fault)... My suggestion for this is to store the rejected rows and try to see which one solves your problem.

Comment: i,e. check some of the lan/id columns for the ones left out and check to see whether you would exclude them. Chose the answer that better solves your problem. For my code just remove the `!` in the last  line `t[!t$lan %in% t2$lan ,]` and check the rejected.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is very hard for us to see and compare our codes for your bigger dataset. I think the safest choice is for you to check as I suggest above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, apologies for my inability to post code in a elegant way in these comments!

Comment: That's ok :). It is very difficult to post code in the comments but it's the only way to show us what you ask. It is not your fault and it is definitely readable.  :)

Comment: @AliciaRosello Is there anything wrong in my code?  It is hard to read all the comments.

Comment: @akrun I don't think there is an error Akrun. Most likely a condition not picked up in one of the codes that makes it produce different results in Alicia's bigger data set. I think it is better if we wait for her to check the rejected rows :)

Comment: @LyzandeR It is a bit strange about the difference in number of columns in the output between your code and mine.  Or is it because the OP added `data$value <-0` initially?

Comment: @akrun ohhh thanks for noticing Akrun. Hadn't seen it. It might be that to be honest. Let's wait and hear back from the OP, but Alicia should take that into account for sure.

Comment: Thank you both! I've checked and LyzandeR's code solved my issue and I'm still not really sure why akrun's code doesn't do the same. I added 'data$value <-0' because my large data frame didn't have this column but that shouldn't affect the difference in the number of rows. In any case, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `duplicated` on "lan", to get the logical index of all elements that are duplicates, repeat the same with both columns together ('id', 'lan'),  to get the elements not duplicated, check which of these elements are TRUE in both cases, negate, and subset.

```
indx1 <-  with(t, duplicated(lan)|duplicated(lan,fromLast=TRUE))
indx2 <- !(duplicated(t[1:2])|duplicated(t[1:2],fromLast=TRUE))
t[!(indx1 & indx2),]
#   id lan      value
#2   2   b 0.84898983
#3   2   c 0.53806582
#4   3   d 0.91657191
#5   3   d 0.30418337
#6   4   e 0.98334817
#7   4   e 0.35612856
#8   4   e 0.05410285
#9   4   f 0.40093459
#11  4   g 0.48845267
```